# Google Scripts Sheets hide/ unhide

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In writing a 'custom function' Google Script for my particular sheet, I simply want to hide a column:

```
function hideColumn(index) {
  // get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get first sheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.hideColumns(index);
}
```

This code works fine when I run it from within the Script editor but if I try to run it from inside a cell "=hideColumn(2)", I get the following error:

"You do not have permission to call **hideColumns** (line 48)."

From the same sheet/ script I'm able to run other custom functions such as:

```
function metersToMiles(meters) {
  if (typeof meters != 'number') {
    return null;
  }
  return meters / 1000 * 0.621371;
}
```

This seems to be some issue with the **hideColumns** function being run from inside a sheet? (ie. custom function?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script 'hideColumn' is not a custom function, but a 'normal script'. Also it does not return anything (whereas the second function does). Only custom functions can be entered like formulas in the spreadsheet. See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) for more info. My advice would be to create an extra menu-item using an onOpen trigger so you can run the function from the (spreadsheet)menu.

Hope that helps ?

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback. 'hideColumn' is a custom function since returning data is not a requisite. However, you're right that a menu-item is the only solution. I hadn't noticed this passage on the google developer pages from the link you sent: **"A custom function cannot affect cells other than those it returns a value to. In other words, a custom function cannot edit arbitrary cells, only the cells it is called from and their adjacent cells. To edit arbitrary cells, use a custom menu to run a function instead."** That's the issue: hideColumns() will faill because it affects other cells.